# Why do we need to specify data= in R?

Tags: r

I have :
why do we use data if it works without it too ?
boxplot(bass[,2]) is enough ?

boxplot( data= bass, bass[,2])

Comment: You only need the `data` argument if you use `boxplot` with a `formula` (in which case terms in the formula must correspond to columns in the `data` object). You don't need a `data` argument if you pass a vector (e.g. a single column of a `data.frame`) or a `data.frame`/`matrix`.

Comment: [continued] `formula` example: `mtcars(wt ~ carb, data = mtcars)`. `data.frame` example: `boxplot(mtcars[c("mpg", "qsec")])`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers:  I think your first sentence is incorrect.  You say you need `data` if you use a formula, "in which case terms in the formula must correspond to columns in the data object".  The formula can contain global variables, it's just that R will look in`data` first.  In fact, `data` is optional:  if it's not present, R will do the plot with global variables alone.

Comment: @user2554330 All terms in a `formula` *should* correspond to columns in `data`. That's the whole purpose of the `formula`+`data` syntax structure (as in e.g. `boxplot`, `lm`, `glm` etc.). Using globals in a `formula` is bad practice and can lead to some nasty surprises. Don't use globals in a `formula`!

Comment: @user2554330 Example on why using globals in a `formula` is bad: Consider this `resp_global <- mtcars$wt[-1]; boxplot(resp_global ~ carb, data = mtcars)`

Answer (score 3):

The `data` argument is ignored unless you use the "formula" method of `boxplot()`.  For example, in a comment @MauritsEvers gave an example like this:

```
boxplot(wt ~ carb, data = mtcars)
```

(I fixed a typo.)  This says to produce a box plot of the `wt` variable, separately for each value in `carb`, where R should look for those variables in the following order:

1. As columns of `mtcars`.
2. As variables visible in the current context (typically the global environment).

In your example `boxplot( data= bass, bass[,2])` you aren't using a formula, so the `data` argument would be ignored.  As you saw you get the same thing from `boxplot(bass[,2])`.